# Referencing client.rb values in a recipe

Tags: chef

How can I get the value for a key in a nodes client.rb via a recipe during chef-client runs?

**Example:**

client.rb

```
path_to_foo "/opt/foo"
```

recipes/default.rb

```
log config[:path_to_foo]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Chef's config through `Chef::Config`.

```
log Chef::Config[:path_to_foo]
```